# How to configure Nginx virtual directory to reach Apache virtual server?

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx

I have a Django website sitting behind an Nginx reverse proxy server.  I want to start blogging with WordPress (WP) so I've created a separate LAMP server (using PHP-FM) running WP.  I want the blog's URI on my website to be "mysite/blog" to maintain a good SEO score.  To do that, I've created an nginx virtual sub-directory that points to the WP blogging site on my LAMP server.  But when I try to connect to the blog from my website, I keep getting a 404 error.  I suspect I need to modify my Apache virtual host settings but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here are the relevant parts of my Nginx config file:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web00.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name web00.mysite.com;
    ...
    location /blog {
        proxy_pass https://cms00.mysite.com;
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant parts of my Apache config file:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/vhosts.conf
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName "cms00.mysite.com"
  Redirect permanent / https://cms00.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName "cms00.mysite.com"
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mysite.com"
  ...
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that WordPress advises you to install WP into your website's document root (in my case /var/www/html/mysite.com), not a separate subdirectory, so that's what I've done.  Many WP plugins won't work if WP is installed into its own subdirectory below the document root.

If I enter "cms00.mysite.com/wp-login.php" into my browser, I get the Wordpress User login page as expected.  But if I enter "web00.mysites.com/blog", I get WP's "Oops! That page can't be found." error.  I can see the 404 error in the Apache log:

```
... "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.0" 404 ...
```

I believe I understand why this is happening.  My request is being passed to the WP server as https::/cms00.mysite.com/blog.  But https://cms00.mysite.com points to the document root /var/www/html/mysite.com which contains all the WP files.  There is no 'blog' subdirectory.  And if I create one, put an HTML file in it, and refresh the page, I see that file.

How can I configure Nginx and/or Apache so that I can reach my WP blog using the URI, https://web00.mysite.com/blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to do three things to make this work.  The first is that you need to add the following line to the vhosts.conf file on the WP server:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    Alias /blog "/var/www/html/mysite.com"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Next, you need to add the following .htaccess file to the WordPress root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(wp-login\.php)
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Finally, log into the WordPress admin via the https://cms00.mysite.com/wp-admin, go to the General Settings, and ensure that these two settings are as shown:

```
WordPress Address (URL): https://cms00.mysite.com/blog
Site Address (URL): https://cms00.mysite.com/blog
```